# Xml failing to show in table

Tags: php, simplexml

I have an XML page `holidays.xml` and a php page `holiday(simplexml).php` i am attempting to show details from the XML page in a table on the php page but to no avail, no error messages are given but no content is displayed, could anyone point me in the right direction?

```
<?php
// load the xml file into a simplexml instance variable
$holiday = simplexml_load_file('holidays.xml');

// draw a table and column headers
echo "<table border=\"1\">";
echo " <th>Title</td>
      <th>Link</td>
      <th>Description</td>
      <th>Published Date</td>
      <th>Guid</th>";

// iterate through the item nodes displaying the contents
foreach ($holiday->item as $holiday) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>{$holiday->title}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$holiday->link}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$holiday->description}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$holiday->pubDate}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$holiday->guid}</td>";
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

holidays.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?> 
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/">
 <channel>
  <title>Special offers on exotic holidays</title> 
  <link>http://www.numyspace.co.uk/~cgel1/holidays/special_offers.html</link> 
  <description>The best site for special offers on exotic holidays.  We offer many special offers in the way of holiday discounts, 
    free room upgrades , free flight upgrades and free child places.</description> 
  <language>en-gb</language> 
  <pubDate>Sun, 13 Feb 2011 00:00:00 GMT</pubDate> 
  <image>
  <title>Special offers for exotic holidays</title> 
  <link>http://www.numyspace.co.uk/~cgel1/holidays/special_offers.html</link> 
  </image>
  <item>
      <title>Luxurious Jamaican holidays | 40% Discount On Accommodation - Book Now!</title> 
      <link>http://www.numyspace.co.uk/~cgel1/holidays/Jamaica.html</link> 
      <description>7 nights at The Golden Palm, Montego Bay travelling from Newcastle with Fly Jamaica</description> 
      <pubDate>Sun, 13 Feb 2011 11:58:17 GMT</pubDate> 
      <guid>http://www.numyspace.co.uk/~cgel1/holidays/Jamaica.html</guid> 
  </item>
  <item>
      <title>Barbados holidays | Royal Wedding special - Free room upgrade</title> 
      <link>http://www.numyspace.co.uk/~cgel1/holidays/Barbados.html</link> 
      <description>10 nights at 5* Pride of Barbados hotel for only £950, travelling on BA from Gatwick</description> 
      <pubDate>Mon, 14 Feb 2011 13:01:10 GMT</pubDate> 
      <guid>http://www.numyspace.co.uk/~cgel1/holidays/Barbados.html</guid> 
  </item>
 </channel>
</rss>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are forgetting channel node in your foreach loop.

Try to put

```
foreach ($holiday->channel->item as $holiday) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>{$holiday->title}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$holiday->link}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$holiday->description}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$holiday->pubDate}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$holiday->guid}</td>";
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
```